# Excel freezes when running a macro which works on another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

when i run the below code on a sample document with a few columns, it works fine but as soon as i run it on a larger document excel just freezes
[SampleDoc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xL1tbTu9pPTcokeLyWcPjIUeKwc0wNFB3Jg0PsnNnBU/edit#gid=733371001)

Sample Doc code

```
Sub RCOps_Compare()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim lRow As Long, v As Variant
   Dim dic As Object, i As Long, rowCount As Long
   Dim jobNo As String, Traveller As String, OpSeq As String
   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = Range("A4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   v = Range("A4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4).Value '31
   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    jobNo = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(0)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A4").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, jobNo & "*"
        rowCount = [subtotal(103,A:A)] - 1
        With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            lRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row + .Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count - 1
        End With
        
        If rowCount = 1 Then
            Traveller = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(1)
            OpSeq = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(2)
                          
            If jobNo = v(i, 2) And Traveller = v(i, 3) And OpSeq = v(i, 4) Then
                Range("D" & i + 1) = "* " & v(i, 4)
                MsgBox (v & " ")
            End If
        Else
            If Not dic.Exists(jobNo) Then
                dic.Add jobNo, Nothing
                Range("D" & lRow) = "* " & v(i + rowCount - 1, 4)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

other version

```
Sub RCOps_Compare()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Dim lRow As Long, v As Variant
   Dim dic As Object, i As Long, rowCount As Long
   Dim jobNo As String, Traveller As String, OpSeq As String
   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = Range("A4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
   v = Range("A4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 4).Value '31
   Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    jobNo = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(0)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A4").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, jobNo & "*"
        rowCount = [subtotal(103,A:A)] - 1
        With rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            lRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row + .Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count - 1
        End With
        
        If rowCount = 1 Then
            Traveller = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(1)
            OpSeq = Split(v(i, 1), "-")(2)
                          '29 30 31
            If jobNo = v(i, 29) And Traveller = v(i, 30) And OpSeq = v(i, 31) Then
                Range("AE" & i + 1) = "* " & v(i, 31)
                MsgBox (v & " ")
            End If
        Else
            If Not dic.Exists(jobNo) Then
                dic.Add jobNo, Nothing
                Range("AE" & lRow) = "* " & v(i + rowCount - 1, 31)
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Im mostly wondering why it will work for one document but wont work for another, bigger document (even though the column numbers have been adjusted), I cant insert an example for the bigger file)

Comment: anytime one interacts with the sheet, vba slows down.  You are iterating an array which is good, but then you are using that value in a filter.  So you filter the same data each time for each item in the array.  If that array is large it will take some time.  When Excel "freezes" it is running the code.  It may take some time with larger sets.  It is not truly frozen just iterating the code.  Wait, eventually it will unfreeze and the results will be displayed.

Comment: Ah ok no worries, i was just a bit concerned because of the length of time it was taking to process